# Any (easy?) way to extract the tooltips from a client side image map (including layout)?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, tooltip, imagemap

**WHAT I HAVE**
• an image map, that I did not create from scratch, linking to images that look similar
• an html document featuring one large image made of very many smaller ones. 
• links, in a grid, densely packed, mapped as rectangles, of the original smaller images
• The ability to view them in place as popups when moused over.
**WHAT I WANT**
• a grid if the actual images really small instead of an image of them
• clickable links instead of popups or an image map
• to retain the present placement precisely
• to manage to communicate clearly and without adverse incident
**WHY I AM HERE**
• it seems like the sort of problem solved easily from someone familiar with such things
• I could not find the answer from researching image maps, etc., and
• it would please me to get the hang of Stack Overflow discourse

*crossing fingers...*

**CODE**
 
also at: http://pastebin.com/FMug1Sfu 
longer version at: http://pastebin.com/FshHZ1b3

```
            <pre>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>you could call it a mosaic</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
                //...not my original code...

                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    var macIE52 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 5.2') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1);

                    function tile(url, comment)
                    {
                        this.url = url;
                        this.comment = comment;
                        return this;
                    }

                    var tiles = new Array();
            tiles[0] = new tile('1-1.jpg', 'http://image-url--0'); 
            tiles[1] = new tile('1-2.jpg', 'http://with-a-number--1 ');
            tiles[2] = new tile('1-3.jpg', 'http://that-i-added--2 ');
            tiles[3] = new tile('1-4.jpg', 'http://in-an-attempt--3' );
            tiles[4] = new tile('1-5.jpg', 'http://-to-tell-them-apart--4');
            tiles[5] = new tile('1-6.jpg', 'http://by-mousing-over--5');
            tiles[6] = new tile('1-7.jpg', 'http://all-two-thousand--6');
            tiles[7] = new tile('1-8.jpg', 'http://tooltipa-individually--7');
            // goes on for a while till 
            tiles[354] = new tile('2-354.jpg', 'http://and-writing-down-the-url--353');


                    var timer = null;

                    function showTile(event, tileNum)
                    {script for showing tiles in popups; view longer version at http://pastebin.com/FshHZ1b3}
                </script>
                <style type="text/css">
                    div.detail
                    {
                        visibility: visible;
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0px;
                        top: 0px;
                        border: solid black thin;
                        padding: 5px;
                        background: white;
                    }
                    p.detailImage
                    {
                        padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
                        border: 0px;
                        margin: 0px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    p.detailText
                    {
                        padding: 0px;
                        border: 0px;
                        margin: 0px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    img.detail
                    {
                        border: solid gray thin;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="detailDiv" class="detail">
                <p class="detailImage"><img name="detailImg" class="detail" src="" alt="Tile image"></p>
                <p id="detailText" class="detailText"></p>
            </div>
            <p>
                <img name="original" src="Original.jpg" alt="Original Image">
                <img name="you could call it a mosaic" src="Mosaic.jpg" usemap="#mosaic" alt="Mosaic">
            </p>
            <map name="you could call it a mosaic">
                <a href="/rady.html#1" name="1"><area shape='rect' coords='978,1049,1043,1120'  onload='showTile(event,0)' onmouseout='hideTile()' document.write('1') alt='Tile'>1</a>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2739,1189,2804,1260'  onmouseover='showTile(event,1)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='1630,1049,1695,1120'  onmouseover='showTile(event,2)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2543,1329,2608,1400'  onmouseover='showTile(event,3)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2804,1749,2869,1820'  onmouseover='showTile(event,4)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2478,69,2543,140'  onmouseover='showTile(event,1)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2347,1609,2413,1680'  onmouseover='showTile(event,5)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='1369,1609,1434,1680'  onmouseover='showTile(event,6)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                <area shape='rect' coords='2021,699,2086,770'  onmouseover='showTile(event,7)' onmouseout='hideTile()' alt='Tile'>
                // goes on for at least a thousand more lines... then
                </map>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit too suspicious, but this appears to be some sort of bot posting. I've never seen a post or question carry a disclaimer and a philosophical quote ("so close, but so far away"). And the question is not clear even though there's a block of text under the heading "Question".

Comment: @noloader The bot just showed up in the JS Room

Comment: @afemalefaust Please do provide some sample markup of what you presently have, and perhaps what you would like to generate.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 - perhaps you can get a concise question out of it if its interactive ;)

Comment: argh the link got garbled, can only edit for five --- *ahem*  @noloader "Here's an update on those flying, dangerous <s>bots</s> space creatures.... They just entered through the loading dock."  http://www.ex.ua/get/944709156505/91061919 (backup link: http://www.ex.ua/944709156505).

Comment: can it be allowed out of <s>the doghouse</s> hold now?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 see above link.  (whatever happened to strikethrough?)

Comment: What happened to strikethrough is that you can only use HTML tags in questions and answers, not in comments. Regarding letting it out of the doghouse, what I think is still missing is an explanation of in which way the code you have doesn't meet the requirements in the "what I want" section. What results are you getting and how do they differ from the desired results? Clarify that, and I'll cast a let-out-of-the-doghouse vote.